# I want to send 100 Tokens but receive 0.0000000000000001 Token? Amount unit256 What is so I can send 100 Token?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, contract-design, tokens, remix

I tried to send 100 Token by multitransfer but received 0.0000000000000001. I performed by remix. How can I send the correct token number I want?

```
 function multitranfer(address[] addrs, uint256 amount) public {
for (uint256 i = 0; i < addrs.length; i++) {
  transfer(addrs[i], amount);
}
```

}

[image]

[image]

Thanks you!

Comment: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html

Comment: The amount it's in Wei so you have to put more 0s there, you have to check how many decimals you have defined on your ERC20 Token. For example if you have 18 decimals that would be (amount)*10**18

Comment: transact to HeroNodeToken.airdropToAddresses errored: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected token * in JSON at position 419